# Reading static variable during its initialization => Flutter Navigator.push

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of statefull widget which I use to navigate from pages. but when I was trying to push these List element in Navigator.push(), it says "Reading static variable during its initialization".

here's the list:

```
List<ActionScreen> fullBodyNavigation = [
          ActionScreen(title: 'demo data', number: 20, gifDirectory: "assets/gifs/demodata.gif", currentList: fullBodyNavigation,
              frameMin: 0, frameMax: 17, milisecondAnimation: 800, milisecondTimer: 800, sessionNumber: 1,),
          ActionScreen(title: 'demodata', number: 15, gifDirectory: "assets/gifs/demodata.gif", currentList: fullBodyNavigation,
              frameMin: 0, frameMax: 30, milisecondAnimation: 1200, milisecondTimer: 1200, sessionNumber: 2,),
          ActionScreen(title: 'demodata', number: 15, gifDirectory: "assets/gifs/demodata.gif", currentList: fullBodyNavigation,
              frameMin: 0, frameMax: 2, milisecondAnimation: 2000, milisecondTimer: 2000, sessionNumber: 3,),
          .............
        ]
```

here's the push method:

```
onPress: () {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => fullBodyNavigation[0],),);
},
```

I foud a solution in stackoverflow which said I have to use 'data' such as "fullBodyNavigation.data[0]". but ide said "getter data is not defined". can anyone pls help?

here's that solution's link: [Reading static variable during its initialization | Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60270040/reading-static-variable-during-its-initialization-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you have created the navigation pages list:

```
    List<ActionScreen> fullBodyNavigation = [
        ActionScreen(title: 'demo data', 
          number: 20, 
          gifDirectory: "assets/gifs/demodata.gif", 
          currentList: fullBodyNavigation,
          frameMin: 0, 
          frameMax: 17,
          milisecondAnimation: 800, 
          milisecondTimer: 800, 
          sessionNumber: 1,
        ),
        .............
    ]
```

Why do you want to pass `currentList: fullBodyNavigation` to `ActionScreen`. So basically, you are trying to access the list inside the list itself. The chicken and egg problem.  THat's what compiler is warning you with the error.

To fix this, dont pass `currentList: fullBodyNavigation` to `ActionScreen`. Instead make `fullBodyNavigation` a static field and in `ActionScreen` just access it with the class name. That should do your thing and also make the compiler happy